# How to create custom masterpage in SPFX classic view

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, spfx

I have created SPFX Project and created Masterpage in classic view and hosted it already in SharePoint online and when I add my SharePoint framework Web parts 
to the master page after 2 days cannot edit anymore on the save or do any actions from SharePoint ribbon however my master page works fine at SharePoint online, SO after a lot of searches I found all people use Modern View but in the modern view, I cannot do any branding to my portal

is there any way to fix this problem or Doc to how to create a master page in the SharePoint framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not able to add branding in Modern Page. You have to use the SharePoint Framework Extensions. By using Application customizer, you can add your customization's in the page placeholders.

[**Here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions) you can start page placeholders in application customizer.

Comment: Yeah i know i cant add branding SharePoint Modern Page So that's why i said i want to create Classic View

Comment: You can set Classic view as your default organization view in Admin Center. If you want to customize the Modern view, you should go with the Application customizer.

Comment: But in Classic View Master Page Stuck and Cannot edit anymore or save or do any actions in SharePoint Ribbon, and am Pretty sure my Master Page is working fine because i used it a lot of time in SharePoint On-premises and SharePoint Online a lot of time

Comment: Are you using your own custom master page or edited the default seatle master?

Comment: I took copy of seatle and created my own custom Master Page based on seatle structure.

Comment: Then there should be an issue with your custom master page.